# AJAX POST Form with encoding "multipart/form-data" Successful But return error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

I am using an HTML Form to submit some data including a file to an HTTP-accessible Java WebService using AJAX. It has input for a file, a radiobutton, a checkbox and a Select Option.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="validate-form">
    <div id="subscribers_csv" class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file" id="subscribersCSV" name="subscribersCSV" />
        </span>
        <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
        <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none">&times;</a>
    </div>

    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="service" id="voicemail" checked value="voicemail" /> Voicemail</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="service" id="voicesms" value="voicesms" /> VoiceSMS</label>

    <div class="toggle" onclick="manageMailboxGroup();"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="check_mailbox_group" id="check_mailbox_group" style="display:none">

    <select class="form-control" name="group_name" id="group_name">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

I am then submitting this through a click event on a button and using AJAX to call the Java WebService.

```
var url= "http://IP:port/ServiceName";
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    data: formData,
    type:"POST",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("AJAX Error");
    }
});
```

When I submit the form, the WebService is called correctly and then processes the data with no issues. However when it returns, it always goes to the "error" callback and alerts "AJAX Error".

Should I be using something else in the form or the AJAX call? I Googled many examples of using multipart forms and they are all similar to what I have here. Thanks.

**ETA:**
I should add that the Java WebService and the HTML/JQuery code are on different servers on the same network. I am getting this in console: **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://IP:Port' is therefore not allowed access."**

Comment: You need to show your `webservice` method!

Comment: One thing you should do is get a unique name for each field in your form.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao, when I submit a regular form with action=URLofWebService, it returns a JSON-formatted response correctly so it shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: @tobifasc, they all have unique names except for the radiobutton which should have the same name.

Comment: i see. 
Is your JSON well formed?

Comment: Do one thing log the error like this - > `error: function(xhr,responseStauts,text) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }` and see what error you are getting

Comment: Yes the JSON is well-formed, I'm parsing it on other pages without any issues.
And I've already tried the error logging and tried it again now, it returns empty and responseStatus returns "error".

Comment: But I don't know why I haven't checked console yet until now. I should add more info now since I just realized it is relevant, the Java WebService and the HTML/JQuery code are on different servers. I am getting this in console: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://IP:Port' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing